# JAVA set property of JButton() using UI Manager

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hey I want to set property : `setContentAreaFilled(false)` for `jbutton`.
I am unable to do this using UI Manager:

```
UIManager.put("Button.contentAreaFilled", false);
```

But the value is not getting changed .
Can anybody please suggest the workaround or flaw in the code.

Comment: try add `setOpaque(false);`

Comment: I wish to do it using UI-Manager. . setOpaque() is set as true.How can i set contentAreaFilled AS false through UIMnager

Comment: By value not getting changed do you mean value of existing JButton? Did you try creating new JButton and checking property?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible using `UIManager`, i've tested it on my pc (Windows 10, jre1.8.0_131) and that key (`Button.contentAreaFilled`) does not exist (i also tried using different `LookAndFeel`s).

You can find a list of `UIManager` keys [here](http://thebadprogrammer.com/swing-uimanager-keys/).

Also, [this link](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) (by Rob Camick) provides a nice GUI to check the keys default value in different LAF installed on your machine (screenshot below).

[image]

You can use a factory method to create all the buttons in your GUI, setting content area filled to false inside the method.

**EDIT**

You can't decide which keys will be used by `ComponentUI` classes, unless you create your own `LookAndFeel`.

For example, if you want to see how `JPanel` default background and other properties are installed, take a look at `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI` class, for example:

```
protected void installDefaults(JPanel p) {
        LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(p,
                                         "Panel.background",
                                         "Panel.foreground",
                                         "Panel.font");
        LookAndFeel.installBorder(p,"Panel.border");
        LookAndFeel.installProperty(p, "opaque", Boolean.TRUE);
    }
```

I would not suggest you to play with this, but if you want you can read:

- [Lesson: Modifying the Look and Feel (from official tutorial)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/)
- [Creating a Custom Look and Feel (By Ralph Kar)](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs3283/ftp/Java/swingConnect/friends/sce/sce.html)

I have never tried it, but i think it could be very painful.

I highly recommend you to use a static factory method to create your buttons: it will be much more simple and safe, for example:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
public class ButtonsFactory
{
    public static JButton createButton (String text) {
        JButton button = new JButton (text);
        button.setContentAreaFilled (false);
        // set any other property ...
        return button;
    }
}
```

Now you can create every button in your application by simply calling:

```
JButton button = ButtonsFactory.createButton ("...");
```

Obviously, you can provide more methods to create a button or another component with different arguments.

Comment: Can you provide a list of keys if possible

Comment: @xyz There can be any number of entries depending on the look and feel

Comment: I am using getSystemLookAndFeel

Comment: @xyz Well, `UIDefault`s is just a `Map`, so you could check to see if key exists or not or if it returns a value or not, but there's no real way to be sure

Comment: @xyz You can use `System.out.println (UIManager.get ("Button.contentAreaFilled"));` to check if a value is set. However, contentAreaFilled as for now isn't contained in the map, in Windows, Nimbus, Metal, GTK and more look and feels, so you should not go this way, even if you find a look and feel where it is set, and i really don't think you will

Comment: @xyz The only other option you have is to supply your own look and feel delegate for `UIButton`, with a little bit of work, you could devise a "proxy" implementation, which basically forwards the majority of work to the existing UI delegate, but which can intercept the installation of the default properties, adding your settings into the mix

Comment: @xyz on doing System.out.println (UIManager.get ("Button.contentAreaFilled"))  I am getting value as false. What does that means

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can you please also look into this issue

Comment: @xyz You should use that print instruction to get the key **before** you write `UIManager.put ("Button.contentAreaFilled", false));`, else you are creating a new key ...

Comment: So if i am creating a new key, UI Manger should pick that key value, rite ?

Comment: @Ansharja yes you are right, but ven though I am craeting a new Key, why is UIMnager not reading those property.

Comment: @xyz It doesn't work like that. You can add **any** key to `UIManager`, the problem is that nobody will use it. You can't decide which keys are gonna be used by the current `LookAndFeel`, unless you provide **your** custom `LookAndFeel`

Comment: Custom Look and feel ? can you please elaborate with some example @Ansharja